# How can I add Id to row with jquery ajax server-side

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I need to add id property to TR of table data dynamically added with jquery ajax server-side and write data there. how can I do that. I add the Json data coming with the code below to the lines.

```
"ajax": {
        "url": '/Siparis/SiparisleriDoldur/',
        "type": 'POST',
        "dataType": 'json',
        "data": { liste }
    },
    "columns":
        [
            { "data": "MusteriAdi", "name": "Müşteri Adı" },
            { "data": "MalzemeAdi", "name": " Ürün Adı" },
            { "data": "SiparisAdet", "name": "Sipariş Adedi" },
        ],
```

i want to do;

```
  <tr id='IdNumber' data-id='IdNumber'>
<td>bla</td>
<td>bla</td>
<td>bla</td>
</tr>
```

Note: IdNumber is in data(json list)

Comment: I assume from the syntax this is a datatable? If that is the case, research the [createdRow](https://datatables.net/reference/option/createdRow) property of the settings. In addition it would appear that the 'server-side-rendering' and 'serverside-javascript' tags are redundant.

Comment: yes its datatable.I want to give the id number that comes with json to the selected line on the datatable, this is what I want to do.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I added an answer for you below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your use of the Datatable library you can use the `createdRow` property of the settings to amend each row as required. Try this:

```js
$('#yourDatatable').dataTable({
  "createdRow": function(row, data, dataIndex) {
    let id = data[0]; // amend 'data[0]' here to be the correct column for your dataset
    $(row).prop('id', id).data('id', id); 
  },
  "ajax": {
    // ...
  },
  // other settings as normal...
});
```

Comment: I'll try, but can't this be done with a columns tag?
 row [ columns[ {},{},{}] ]

Comment: No, as columns is regarding the `td` elements, not the parent `tr`. It is also unable to set an attribute on the `td` elements. All it does is set what data from the AJAX result should be displayed in which column.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my problem with;

```
"createdRow": function (row, data) {
            var id = data.Id;
            $(row).prop('id', id).data('id', id);
            $(row).attr('data-id', id).data('data-id', id);
        },
```

Comment: Thank you for posting your final solution. So, basically, Rory's answer was correct and gave you the info you needed to get the job done. We are happy to see that the problem is solved. Please accept *(click the checkmark beside the answer)* Rory's answer to close out this question, and please continue to participate on StackOverflow. Your question was well formed, you updated everyone on your final code - you are exactly the type of member we want on here.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution:

```
"columns": [
  {
    "title": 'Malzeme Türü',
    "createdCell": function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
      $(td).attr('id', "itemTypeDisplay");
    },
    "defaultContent": '',
    "data": "itemTypeDisplay",
  }
]
```